# Dynamically add/remove/sort input boxes using the jQuery 2.1.0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: Like the picture shows.]

I want to implement like this photo features,but I have no idea,Please experts help me to resolve the question Thanks a lot.

jQuery 2.1.0

Comment: Please post the code that you have or have attempted.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Hello~ I want to press the Add button to dynamically output the text input box and can remove and sort